# How can Java determine if running on AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

What's the fastest way, in terms of execution time, for a Java JVM to determine if it's running on an AWS EC2 instance?

My current method is to do an http fetch to `http://169.254.169.254/latest/instance-id`, but that takes several seconds to time out when I'm not running on AWS.

**Update:**

My solution was to look at the Java system property "user.name" and see if it contained "ec2". We always run our app under the "ec2-user" user name so this method is fast and reliable.

Comment: what is your setup in AWS?  You could easily add some environment variable to your AWS instance and query that.

Comment: Yup, that could work. It would be nice if such a thing already existed, though, because I will probably forget to add a startup script the next time I create an AMI.

Comment: Are you unable to set an environment variable when launching the EC2 instances, that would make this clear?

Answer (score 11):

AWS has documentation for: [Determining an Application’s Current Region](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/determining-an-applications-current-region/).

Regarding their API "The new Regions.getCurrentRegion() method makes this a lot easier. For example, if you start an Amazon EC2 instance in us-west-1 and run your application on that instance, it would know it’s running in us-west-1 and you could use that information to easily configure your application to talk to other services in us-west-1."

.. and here is a code **snippet** with the key words you're looking for to get you going in the right direction:

```
// When running on an Amazon EC2 instance, this method
// will tell you what region your application is in
Region region = Regions.getCurrentRegion();
```

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: @АндрейБеньковский Context added.

Comment: basically, check if `region` is null is the full answer.

Comment: Note that this will perform network calls to the EC2 metadata service and retry them if they fail. If this code is not run on EC2, your application will hang whilst all retires fail.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to change your DNS timeout and retries settings to reduce that time spent. Add the following to the /etc/resolv.conf file and see if it helps. Manpage on resolv.conf will have details.

```
options timeout:1 attempts:1 rotate
```

This is not a direct fix but might address the issue with your current method. Also changes to resolv.conf should take effect immediately.

I am interested in this same thing on my systems.

Answer (score -1):

EC2 instances using Amazon's default Linux run the SSM agent (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-install-ssm-agent.html), so I just check for its presence. It's usually a better indicator than the user, although it's not as fast a looking up an environment property like your update. You could of course set that property when launching the JVM though and achieve the same results:

```java
boolean isEC2 = new java.io.File("/usr/bin/amazon-ssm-agent").exists();
```

Comment: That is very specific to the local OS configuration.